# Laravel dispatch plain json on queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have 2 simple questions overall. Im currently looking into some event handling in Laravel and would like to use RabbitMQ as my event store. Therefor i installed this package to start with: https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev

To get started i registered it and i am able to push messages on to RabbitMQ:

```
$job = (new Sendemail())->onQueue('email')->onConnection('interop');
dispatch($job);
```

The problem however is that Laravel pushes a certain format on the queue and i can't figure out how to change that. An example message would be:

```
{
    "job":"Illuminate\\\\Queue\\\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
    "data":{
        "command":"O:29:\\"Acme\\Jobs\\FooJob\\":4:{s:11:\\"fooBar\\";s:7:\\"abc-123\\";s:5:\\"queue\\";N;s:5:\\"delay\\";N;s:6:\\"\\u0000*\\u0000job\\";N;}"
    }
}
```

So the question is, how can i change this? The main reason on this is that the consumer side is not even a PHP application which also can not interpret the PHP serialized model. Therefor im looking for a way to push a plain JSON object instead.

From the other hand i would also like to understand how you could build a custom listener? For the listener the same thing happens. Laravel tries to read the method but when i push plain JSON this will never work. Isn't there a way to register a handler on a topic and do further handling of the payload of the message within the handler itself?

Comment: something like `dispatch(deserialize($job->getData()))`

Comment: Dispatch requires an object. Deserialize is not a valid php function and the job has no getData method available?

Comment: One other option to consider, since the main point of the Laravel Queue infrastructure is to have Laravel both send and process the jobs would to just use [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) directly. You'd then have full control over what gets pushed onto the queue.

Comment: Depending on your language, there are libraries to deserialize something created by PHP's serialize function: https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-unserialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [laravel-queue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/laravel-queue) library that works with the php-enqueue library you linked to make it compatible with [Laravel's built in queue system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) that Florian mentioned.

By default, it will still use a serialized object, but I think that can be overridden. If you look in [Queue.php, createObjectPayload() on line 130](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php#L138) in the core Laravel Framework, that's where the job is being serialized.

If you extend the Queue class in the laravel-queue library, you should be able to change createObjectPayload to look something like this:

```php
protected function createObjectPayload($job, $queue)
{
    $payload = $this->withCreatePayloadHooks($queue, [
        'displayName' => $this->getDisplayName($job),
        'job' => 'Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call',
        'maxTries' => $job->tries ?? null,
        'timeout' => $job->timeout ?? null,
        'timeoutAt' => $this->getJobExpiration($job),
        'data' => [
            'commandName' => $job,
            'command' => $job,
        ],
    ]);
    return array_merge($payload, [
        'data' => [
            'commandName' => get_class($job),
            'command' => json_encode(clone $job),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

That should JSON encode the job data instead of serializing it. You may even be able to remove the encoding altogether, as I think it's already JSON encoded somewhere up the chain.

Comment: Seems logic somehow, let me try to implement something. I assume the same goes then for the listener (if i would build something in PHP right?) Since the fact in default expects a certain message format in this case which is Laravel specific

Comment: @Dirkos If your listener is built in PHP, you'd be able to use the serialize function, so this wouldn't be an issue, right? If you're using a non-PHP listener, then you'd be writing from scratch anyway.

Comment: Yeah initially it will be PHP but will be translated later to other languages so. I also dont really like to bind my queues to specific framework implementations to be honest so guess its fine to decouple it now right away

Comment: @Dirkos In that case, if you confirm something link my answer will work, consider keeping the serialize format until you decide to switch to a non-PHP processor. That will allow you to use the full Laravel Queue infrastructure for now and then just override the Queue class later when you're ready to switch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way for your purpose:
First install this package for `rabbit`:

```
vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq
```

and in controller:

```
Queue::connection('rabbitmq')->pushRaw('{you can generate a json format here}', 'queue_name');
```

you can generate a `json` and put in this command.