# Pulling Data from AWS SQS and Update to ElasticSearch Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, supervisord

I am new to AWS and Laravel. I am trying to pull messages from AWS SQS using `$client->receiveMessage` method. Each message contains an id value `{'id': 'dynamic-id'}` which used to read data from database `(mysql)` and update the data to `elastic search`. Below is my code which is doing the above functionality. Also the messages are adding from `lambda`.

```
    use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient; 
    use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

    $client = new SqsClient([
      'region' => 'my-region',
      'version' => '2012-11-05'
    ]);

    while(true) {
      try {
        $result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
            'AttributeNames' => ['SentTimestamp'],
            'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 1,
            'MessageAttributeNames' => ['All'],
            'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl, // REQUIRED
            'WaitTimeSeconds' => 5,
        ));
        if (!empty($result->get('Messages'))) {
            $idJSON = json_decode($result->get('Messages')[0]['Body'], true);
            static::update_to_elastic_search($idJSON['id']);
            $result = $client->deleteMessage([
              'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl, // REQUIRED
              'ReceiptHandle' => $result->get('Messages')[0]['ReceiptHandle'] // REQUIRED
            ]);
        } else {
            echo "No messages in queue. \n";
        }
      } catch (AwsException $e) {
          // output error message if fails
          error_log($e->getMessage());
      }
    }
```

Currently I am running this code from `php artisan tinker` console using a class object and method.

```
$s = new SQSAws;
$s->recive_message_from_sqs_and_update_to_es();
```

I want to run this continuously without any manual intervention. Whenever a message push to queue the code will read and update the data. Is there any way I can do that? I tried with laravel queue but again I have to maintain that queue in another database.

Comment: [Laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) support SQL so you can probably rewrite this code as a job. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380909/laravel-dispatch-plain-json-on-queue) has a similar issue and the proposed solution was to use [laravel-queue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/laravel-queue)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, I tried with queue but that become complex again, so I want another suggestion where I can run that task using supervisor in production.

Comment: You could make this code into an artisan command and run that the same way you'd run the queue worker.

Comment: @apokryfos, yes I am thinking about that. Thanks for your support. So, I can run the command using supervisor also, right?

Comment: Yes, the Laravel queue worker is doing this the source of that command is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/ListenCommand.php) if you want to go down that rabbit hole.